# How to start a snap application from the terminal?

Tags: snap

I'm logging in to an ssh -X session and I can't figure out how to start the snap version of IntelliJ.

I can see an entry

```
./snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/401/bin/idea.sh
```

I would like to execute this.

Comment: 'snap run application' - on my computer it works.

Answer (score 0):

As Mahler suggested

```
snap run intellij-idea-ultimate
```

For some reason the `run` command is listed in the development section of the snap man file.